# Next.js app doesn't seem to preserve global context provider set up within _app.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have my next.js app set up with a global context/provider dealy:

`_app.js`:

```
import {useState} from "react"
import GlobalContext from "components/GlobalContext"

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(null)

    let contextValues = {
        isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn
    }

    return (
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={contextValues}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default MyApp
```

`components/GlobalContext.js`:

```
const { createContext } = require("react")

const GlobalContext = createContext()
export default GlobalContext
```

When I call `setIsLoggedIn(true)` elsewhere in the app... it appears to be set just fine, but then when I navigate to a different page, it seems this global state gets blasted away and isLoggedIn is set back to false.

Is this how it's supposed to work?

How should I manage global state such as this, and also have it persist across page loads?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, every time you go to a different page, the function `MyApp` is run, so a new 'instance' of the component's state is created.

To reuse the state, it sould be stored in a global state. I did that using an external redux store, and calling it from myapp. This store is a global variable and it's reused if it exists. Kind of the 'singleton' pattern.

```
let store: Store<StoreState, Action>;

const initStore = () => {
  if (!store) {
    store = createStore(reducer, initialState);
  }
  return store;
};
export const useStore = () => initStore();
```

Them from MyApp

```
import { useStore } from '../store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

export default class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    const store = useStore();
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
         <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

You can maybe do the same without redux. The key is to keep the state as global variable.

However, this will work only from client side navigation. If you retrieve a page using server side, you'll lose the state, you'll need to use sessions or cookies for that.

You can also check this example from nextjs:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux